# Проверка баланса кошелька EasyPay

Tags: php

Для реализации бота необходимо реализовать либо проверку статуса платежа по заданным параметрам, либо проверку баланса определённого кошелька на PHP. Не могу ничего отыскать ((
Может кто сталкивался, как реализовать?

Comment: Из формы проверки операции с главной страницы easypay.ua вытащил следующий путь: https://easypay.ua/main/GetTransactionStatus

Comment: при отправке POST inputData=[id операции] можно получить статус платежа и точное время. Но нет инфы о сумме( А без суммы проверка бесполезна((

Comment: я конечно могу реализовать приложение на плюсах или C#, которое будет через элемент браузер авторизироваться в изипей и анализировать выдаваемый html, но это обходной путь, а не решение..